# When I use While Loop my Code no Longer works

Tags: python, loops

```
import pyautogui
import pydirectinput
import time


x = 1
while x <190:
 for number in range(190):
  time.sleep(0.1)
  pyautogui.click(480, 595)
  x = x+1
  if x == 190:
  

   pydirectinput.keyDown('shiftleft')
   time.sleep(2.5)
   pydirectinput.keyUp('shiftleft')
   x = 1
```

When I run this all it does is repeat the first code and does not activate the second code I am a newb at coding so I don't know why this is happening. It just activates the 2nd "x = 1" instead of doing the code above it first then resetting the loop.
I want the code to run indefinitely but run both codes instead of only the click code

What should I put in after "if x == 190:"

Answer (score 1):

A while loop executes the code inside its body as long as its condition evaluates to `true`. Your condition is whether `x` is equal to `1` or not.

You initialize `x` to `1`, but you never change its value in your while loop's body. So, the condition is always `true`, and you have an infinite loop.

You need to modify the value of `x` inside your while loop to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

````
import pydirectinput
import time


x = 1
while x == 1:
 for number in range(190):
  time.sleep(0.1)
  pyautogui.click(480, 595)

 pydirectinput.keyDown('shiftleft')
 time.sleep(2.5)
 pydirectinput.keyUp('shiftleft') ```
````

Comment: Yes, just what I was thinking. However, even the variable `x` is redundant. Just use `while True:`. No `x` needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).